# How to get the next ul element on click of the current li in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some `ul` and `li` element for my sidebar. I need to `slideDown()` the next `ul` on `click` of the current `li` item. I have tried some but no luck. Here are my attempts below.

My HTML code:

```
<li class="parent-li">Reports
    <i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:10px;color:red;"></i>
    <ul>
        <li>Report1</li>
        <li>Report2</li>
        <li>Report3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
$('parent-li').on("click", function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
});
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Add dot  - $('.parent-li') .. And $(this).find('ul')

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita yes it is a solution but I have to use also find with it suggested in other answer. thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .[next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)() looks for the siblings of an element and the target ul element is the child element, you should select the ul element by using .[children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)() or .[find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)().

and please correct your selector for li element as class selector start with a Dot . Here is an example.

```js
$('.parent-li').on("click", function() {
  $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.hide
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent-li">Reports
  <i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:10px;color:red;"></i> 
  <ul class="hide">
    <li>Report1</li>
    <li>Report2</li>
    <li>Report3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.find()`, like this:

```
$('parent-li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The UL you're trying to slide down is actually nested within the LI so your code will not find the UL within your LI. Also you need to add a dot to your CSS selector to find the LI with the class of 'parent-li'

Try something like below instead:

```
$('.parent-li').on("click", function(){
     // the .first() is optional but it'll find the first UL inside the LI
     $(this).find('ul').first().slideDown(); 
});
```